# A Simple Countdown with for loop

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to create a simple countdown.
Here is my code but it's not working.
Can you help me find the problem?

```
function count() {
    for (var cc=20,cc > 0,cc--) {
        document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML=cc;
    }
}
count();
```

Comment: What is the problem? from what I see it can be either you lack a sleep of some sort or you have no element with `id="coo"`, or the `,` instead of `;` typo in the for loop.

Comment: The problem is his comma's instead of semi-colons in the for argument. Otherwise you are right, in this manner (without a 'sleep/pauze' like a recursive setInterval(f,t), the element cco will only have 0 visible.

Comment: @OfirFarchy, what JavaScript version are you using that it has sleep? ;)

Comment: @epascarello, correct :) language mixup, fixed the comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using commas instead of semicolons.

```
for (var cc=20,cc > 0,cc--)
```

should be

```
for (var cc=20;cc > 0;cc--)
```

However, this probably won't do what you think it will, as the loop will count all the way to 0 immediately  (so the user won't even see the countdown). I'm guessing you wanted something like:

```
var cc = 20;

var interval = setInterval(function()
{
    document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML = -- cc;

    if (cc == 0)
        clearInterval(interval);

}, 1000);
```

See [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) for more information.

Comment: Looks like you need to add a `clearInterval` in case `cc` is `0`.

Comment: Or you could use a recursive `setTimeout` that stops setting when `cc` is `0`.

Comment: Yes, you're right - admittedly, I didn't test the code. Thanks!

Comment: @mellamokb Although in this situation it probably doesn't matter, I find `setInterval` is more precise with the interval than a recursive `setTimeout`. There's a good description of the difference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/712294).

Answer (score 4):

There are (at least) two mistakes.

The first is syntactical: In a for loop the parameters are separated by `;` and not by `,`. Syntactic correct code would look like this:

```
function count() {
  for (var cc=20;cc > 0;cc--) {
    document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML=cc;
 }
}
```

Second, you do not have a countdown, but override the very same element over and over again, without any time for the user to see the result.

A better approach would be to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) here, which could look like this:

```
var cc = 20;
function count() {
  document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML=cc;
  if ( cc > 0 ) {
    setTimeout( count, 1000 );
  }
}

setTimeout( count, 1000 );
```

The `setTimeout()` approach leaves some time for the browser to actually render your modifications (and for the user to see it).

Comment: +1 I prefer `setTimeout`.  It's like using a [Thorium nuclear reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium-based_nuclear_power) instead of a Uranium one.

Answer (score 3):

When making countdown make sure that start and end elements are correct.

Count up:

```
for (var x=0;x < 10;x++) console.log(x);
```

goes from **0 to 9**

Incorrect countdown:

```
for (var x=10;x > 0;x--) console.log(x);
```

goes from **10 to 1**

Correct countdown:

```
for (var x=10-1;x >= 0;x--) console.log(x);
```

goes from **9 to 0**

Answer (score 1):

Change `','` with `';'` in your for loop

```
function count() {
  for (var cc=20;cc > 0;cc--) {
    document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML=cc
  }
}
count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another recursive version with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
(function count(cc) {
  document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML = cc;
  if (cc > 0)
    setTimeout(function() { count(--cc); }, 1000);
})(10);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DgWgx/